# Remove /components/ from Popular Tags Cloud module

Tags: component, module, jroute

I have set up a page called `domain.com/tags.html` on the root which links to the com_tags component and shows a set of tags most used.

I also want to use the Popular tag cloud module, `mod_tags_popular`, together these two sections should show the same URL for the same tag, but they don't.

In the component menu item, I can see the URL for a tag as:
http://domain.com/tags/tag/19-tagx.html

and in the module as:
http://domain.com/component/tags/tag/19-tagx.html

What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: The URL's appear to be the same on your question, unless my eyes are playing tricks on me

Comment: Same here... ;)

Comment: Dammit, that's wrong

Comment: Sorry, it's edited now.

Comment: Since one is a component and one is a module the URL is constructed differently. You could create a URL alias in a .htaccess so one will be overwritten.

Comment: What are you using to setup the domain.com/tags.html page? Also as far as I know, com_tags doesn't provide a view for the most used tags. How you went about this? The component/tags/tag/19-tagx.html, denotes that there is no itemid for the tags component that would help create a nicer url